# how to run perl in kbuild makefile

Tags: perl, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to add new feature to the current build. to compile, I've add obj-y += mynewfeature.c into the makefile in the same directory. But i still need to generate or update existing header file using a perl script from the same directory. the problem i can't deal with is how to call this perl script from kbuild file. it seems makefile cannot locate the right path to perl script. So what should I add to top of kbuild file to call this perl script file

Thanks

```
dir
 |- mynewfeature.c
 |- generator.pl
 |- some_template //perl script will read this file and generate a header file
 |- Makefile

Makefile:
code_to_call_perl_script // how to write this line
obj-y += mynewfeature.o
```

I've tried Ian's code, perl script not even executed. so is there a way to force a perl execution?

Comment: Did you try `$(shell perl_script)` to call the script?

Comment: @kurtfu Yes, But what bother me is that i dont know how to get right path to file, running this command failed with no such file or directory error

Comment: What was the exact command that you used to call the script from the Makefile? And are there any other perl scripts? If not, maybe you can use the `find` command to get the exact path?

Answer (score 2):

The Makefile rules should be something like this:

```
obj-y += mynewfeature.o

# Add dependency: mynewfeature.o depends on generated header mynewheader.h.
# Note: Generated sources go in $(obj).
$(obj)/mynewfeature.o: $(obj)/mynewheader.h

# Add rule to generate the header file mynewheader.h.
# It depends on the script and the template file.
# Note: Generated sources go in $(obj).
$(obj)/mynewheader.h: $(src)/generator.pl $(src)/some_template
    # (I don't know the exact command you use, but here is an example)
    $(PERL) -s $(src)/generator.pl $(src)/some_template > $@

# Allow generated header file to be cleaned by "make clean".
clean-files := mynewheader.h
```

Reference: [Special Rules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#special-rules) in [Linux Kernel Makefiles](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html) in [Kernel Build System](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/index.html) in [The Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/index.html).

For a concrete example, see the generation of "53c700_d.h" in [drivers/scsi/Makefile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/Makefile).

Comment: it seems that $(src) is not pointed to current folder, but its parent folder and out/target folder. is it possible to force makefile executed in current folder? Thanks